# How to write code in c++ to get the grayscale image pixel brightness?

Tags: c++, image, visual-c++, pixel

I have set of gray scale images.
And i  would like to know the pixel brightness value of each images to compare.
I am new to C++. 
Can anyone help me to find the pixel brightness value?

Comment: For grey scale, R=G=B, so pick one and there's your value.

Comment: What format?  What file io and/or image processing library used?